# Seeing if a index is negaitve

Tags: java, string, indexof

I am writing a program for my structured programming class and we have to take a input string, break it into 3 substrings and then check to see if all three names are there. I have the string broken up at the spaces and now I just need to check that there are three spaces. My professor told us that we had to make sure that there is a space between each name. He told me to simply test if the index of the space character is -1, because if it is the space wont be there. I just cant find a way to test it without getting a "string index out of range" error. Any help would be much appreciated. This is the code I am using to test the input string.

```
System.out.println("Enter filer full name (First Middle Last):");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String fullName = input.nextLine();
                int n = fullName.indexOf(' ');
                int m = fullName.indexOf(' ', n + 1);
                    String firstName = fullName.substring(0, n);
                    String middleName = fullName.substring(n + 1, m);
                    String lastName = fullName.substring(m + 1);
```

Comment: `if (n > -1 && m > -1)`

Answer (score 2):

Before you take the substrings, use`if(n >-1 && m > -1)` to tell if you have the spaces. Your new code would look something like this

```
System.out.println("Enter filer full name (First Middle Last):");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String fullName = input.nextLine();
int n = fullName.indexOf(' ');
int m = fullName.indexOf(' ', n + 1);
if(n>-1&&m>-1){
    String firstName = fullName.substring(0, n);
    String middleName = fullName.substring(n + 1, m);
    String lastName = fullName.substring(m + 1);
}else{
    System.out.println("Don't have spaces!");
}
```

Comment: If I use this method would I still be able to print the firstName, middleName, and lastName later on? Sorry if thats a dumb question I am really new to programming

Comment: @jzaunegger If there's not two spaces, there aren't 3 names, so no, you cannot print them later (they don't exist). --- If you meant "can I use the 3 variables after the `if` statement ends", then yes, you can change the code to allow that, but what would you like the 3 variables to contain if only 2 names were present? If only 1 name was present?

Comment: Sorry I meant if there are two spaces, I need to print them later and the IDE is saying it cant resolve them to a variable, so I was wondering if that was possible

Comment: @jzaunegger What do you mean? Are the spaces being added? Can you show us the error or your code? That will be helpful.

Comment: Also @andreas the full comment did not load for me, but yes i would like to use the three variables after the if statement. So how would I go about initializing the three variables after that. Would I have to move the rest of my code inside the braces of the if statement?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 firstName cannot be resolved to a variable
 middleName cannot be resolved to a variable
 lastName cannot be resolved to a variable

 at IncomeTax.main(IncomeTax.java:116)

Comment: @jzaunegger Are you saying you would like to refer to firstname, middlename, and lastname outside the if statement? If so, there are two ways. 1- place all the code inside the if block 2 - declare the three variables outside. However, if the second step is dependent on there being spaces, the code should probably go inside.

Comment: @FlamingPickle Alright I'll just move everything to inside the if block. Thanks for all the help guys

Comment: @jzaunegger No problem. If this worked for you, could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` returns negative one if the input is not contained in the String. Also, String indices start at zero. So to test for it you would do something like this:

```
if (fullName.indexOf(" ") == -1)
{
  System.out.print("Space not contained in fullName");
} //end if
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just using a split

```
 String fullname = "Scary Old Wombat";
 String [] names = fullname.split (" ");

 assert (names.length == 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `indexOf()` method for this.

Eg:

`if(fullName.indexOf(' ') == -1){
    // index of space is -1, means space is not present
}`

Answer (score 0):

Some names may or may not have a middle name as in `John Doe` while some names may have a middle name that comprises of more than 2 names as in `John Smith Williams Joseph Doe`. 
Hence you can try this!

```
System.out.println("Enter filer full name (First Middle Last):");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String fullName = input.nextLine();
String name [] = fullName.split(" ");
if(name.length == 1) {
    System.out.println("You don't have spaces in the name");
}
else
   if(name.length == 2) {
     System.out.println("First Name: " + name[0]);
     System.out.println("Last Name: " + name[1]);
}else
    if(name.length > 2) {
     System.out.println("First Name: " + name[0]);
     System.out.print("Middle Name: ");
       for (int i = 1; i < (name.length-1) ; i++) {
            System.out.print(name[i] + " ");
       }
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("Last Name: " + name[(name.length-1)]);
}
```

Output - 
`Enter filer full name (First Middle Last):
John Smith Williams Joseph Doe
First Name: John
Middle Name: Smith Williams Joseph 
Last Name: Doe`